# Is there a quick way to disable all plugins?

Tags: ee2

Installed a new module and now the site is insanely slow - stylesheets in the CP aren't loading even, 5-10 minute wait per page load. Is there any way to disable all the plugins at once? Deleting them from the third_party folder didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable all **extensions** (which is the likely culprit, as a module doesn't have the power to inject anything into *all* of the control panel) by editing your **/system/expressionengine/config/config.php** file like so:

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```

This temporarily stops all extensions from loading, but does not actually uninstall them.

To *uninstall* any accessory, extension, or module, simply delete the appropriate row(s) from `exp_accessories`, `exp_extensions`, and `exp_modules` respectively.

You might want to turn on the [Template Debugger](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html#display-template-debugging) first though, to try and find the culprit that way.